# How to determine where programs are currently installed Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a computer running windows 7, with 4 HDDs of various sizes. I've been pursuing a steady upgrade path, where each HDD is large enough to store a previous two. My issue is, I want to know if one of the smaller drives I wish to remove has any currently installed programs. There is a Program Files directory on the drive I want to remove, with a few Adobe products, some games, some minor, deletable, uninstallable programs, but I don't want to have to uninstall every program I see a listing for in that Program Files directory. I'm not even sure if any of these programs are currently installed.

So, is there a way to see what programs are currently installed on drive F:\ , for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open that *Program Files* directory, determine the program names, then use the Registry Editor (`Start / Run / regedit`) and check the following values:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Sostware\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<GUID or Program Name>\InstallLocation

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<GUID or Program Name>\InstallLocation
```

The **InstallLocation** string value (REG_SZ) *should* contain the path to the directory where a program is installed, so if any of the *InstallLocation* strings match with directories under F:'s *Program Files*, you'll have found the programs that'll break if you simply get rid of the files.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Lucky for me, there are only a couple.